# Zombie movies: "body protection" VS "sexy clothes"

Tags: zombie

I really love zombie movies, but one thing that I really hate is (for instance in walking dead) the "humans" walk in "shorts" and "tops", bare arms, big neckline, etc knowing that they will be bitten and die......

I am sure that the movie producers want to "invite" more viewers with more skin and boobs, but what the hell... why can't they just pickup a "moto leather jacket" (really hard for a zombie to bite)?

"*Would it be a crappy movie if*" / *"Why there are no movies where*" every character that appears in the beginning of the story would survive all the way using this kind of tactics (full body protection)?

I don't know but this is what I would do: TRY TO STAY ALIVE and forget the fashion trends.

Comment: If there was absolutely no threat of the characters dying it would take out all the suspense, likely making the movie worse (though not necessarily "crappy"). Besides, given that zombies in most universes are shown to be able to rip somebody open using their fingers, it's possible they can bite through a lot of things we'd consider impossible to bite through.

Comment: I am rather sure that the answer to this question should involve a series of tropes :-)

Comment: Hi Dryadwoods. While your topic is enjoyable to discuss, this site is for questions and answers. Questions should be to the point and as clearly answerable as possible (see [the FAQ](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq)). What is your question here, exactly?

Comment: @Dryadwoods , this could be rephrased to ask if there are any instances where armour stopped a zombie.  This could shed light on your question indirectly through the story or challenges within; or, in commentary upon the legitimate question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haha... I have had this thought MANY times... chain mail and a divers suit for me :P I think the practicality of the movie isn't really considered when making anything in the Zombie genre just because it is a very popular topic right now and the writers are trying to pull in everyone they can.

As far as why they dress like that, it may be for mobility. If you are being chased by a mass hoard and you have thick clothes on (especially in the summer) it can get tough to run. Not to mention that there is normally no way to take a bath or shower, so to keep from dying of stench, they wear clothes that can air out. There are other reasons I am sure, but these are the two main ones that come to mind.

I could very well see a movie or story with iron clad or leather bound survivors being a hit just because it would make it that much more realistic (or at least a lot less girly screaming and running). Maybe you should try and commission or write a story based on that premise!